# Is there a way to limit the touch area for a drag gesture using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, gesture

I would like to have a symbol and some text move together with a drag gesture, but I would like to only have the gesture recognized and drag based upon touching the symbol, not the text also. Right now, getting the drag working is fine, but the position and drag are based on the combination of the symbol and text.  Here is a simple example:

DragView() - the view I'm dragging in this example:

```
struct DragView: View {
    
    @State private var newPos: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        let drag = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { drag in
                newPos = drag.location
            }
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                Text("This is longish Text")
            }
        }
        .position(newPos)
        .gesture(drag)
    }
}
```

And here is my Content View for this example

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                DragView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to initiate the drag only when touching and dragging on the symbol, but have the text follow. Right now when I touch the symbol, the whole view snaps to the middle during the drag, I'm assuming because the position is the middle of the combination of the symbol and the text. I want to keep the text in DragView as I have a model in the background with an array of objects and I want to create an instance of DragView for each item in the model and don't want ContentView to know too many details about what is going on in DragView.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting .gesture() as a modifier of just the image instead of the whole ZStack.

```
struct DragView: View {
    
    @State private var newPos: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        let drag = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { drag in
                newPos = drag.location
            }
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .gesture(drag) //Here
                Text("This is longish Text")
            }
        }
        .position(newPos)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but then the drag doesn't work. I think the whole View has to drag so that moving the gesture inside the ZStack is somehow blocking the gesture? (i.e. from ContentView's perspective, DragView is a single View and is defined by what is contained in the ZStack?) - I'm new at this, but in my head this sounds reasonable :)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct dragtest: View {
    @State var yoffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var ypos: CGFloat = 0
    @State var xoffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var xpos: CGFloat = 0

 
     var body: some View {
         let drag = DragGesture()
             .onChanged { value in
             
          
                 yoffset = ypos+value.translation.height
                 xoffset = xpos+value.translation.width


             }
             .onEnded { value in
                ypos = yoffset
                xpos = xoffset
             }
         ZStack {
             HStack {
             
             
                 Image(systemName: "trash")
                     .font(.largeTitle)
                     .offset(y: yoffset)
                     .offset(x: xoffset)
                     .gesture(drag)
                 
             
                 Text("This is longish Text")
                     .offset(y: yoffset)
                     .offset(x: xoffset)
             }
         }
     
     }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).